# Executar projeto no netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Estou querendo atualizar um projeto, mas ao abrir o mesmo no netbeans, não dá a opção de executar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo essa pergunta do [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385641/3473971) gringo:

> Basta desabilitar a opcao "Compile and Save" e reiniciar o Netbeans.

Mas esta [outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38176492/3473971) explica melhor o que realmente esta acontecendo:

> Isto acontece quando voce fecha o Netbeans enquanto ainda tem erros no codigo e a opcao "compile on save" esta ativada.
>   Pra resolver, delete a pasta Build do diretorio do seu projeto e reinicie o Netbeans.

Comment: onde desabilita?

Comment: @Carlos to no meu Mac entao nao tenho o Netbeans instalado, mas da uma olhada na outra resposta que adicionei, provavelmente ja resolve seu problema.

Comment: A segunda opção resolveu. Muito obrigado!